# Facing problem with the Sorted function and its key value

Tags: python

Can anyone explain this following code, that I am trying to figure out.

```
order = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1357902468'
print(*sorted(input(), key=order.index), sep='')
```

What * is used for? And how does this code arrange the order of the given string?

Comment: look like * list

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk before the list does the list unpacking.
Let's imagine that you have a list like that:

```
lst = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

and you want to print it. But printing it like a list would output:

```
print(lst)
# ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

If you want to output it without the brackets you may try something like:

```
print(lst[0], lst[1], lst[2])
```

Not an elegant solution, right? That means that you wish to convert the list of strings into "something of strings" that you can pass as arguments to print. That is what the list unpacking does:

```
print(*lst)
# string1 string2 string3
```

Adding a separator removes the spaces:

```
print(*lst, sep='')
# string1string2string3'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, `*` is used to expand a list. For example, the following function accepts any number of arguments:

```
def func(*args):
    print(args)
```

and the follwing snippet prints all elements of `my_list` separated by a space:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(*my_list)
# a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

It unpacks the list. If you were to just use

```py
print(sorted("123"))
```

Python would print `['1','2','3']`. However, when you use

```py
print(*sorted("123"))
```

Python sees `print('1','2','3')` and prints those instead of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` used, is an iterable unpacking operator, which takes a list of values, and returns them as a string. Sort of equivalent of `"".join(list)`. Since the function `sorted()` has a list as return type, we need to explicitly convert it into string for our purpose.

```
*sorted(input(), key=order.index), sep=''
```

- Here sorted() function takes in user input via `input()`.
- A custom key function is supplied to customize the sort order of the 
  function. i.e. now characters will be sorted in
  `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1357902468` this
  order.
- `sep=''` strips (sort of) any whitespaces in the string.